# Create array with many arrays inside which are created from one big array on special condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, foreach

```
  // n number of those
  let array1 = [1,3,3,6] 
  let array2 = [4,7,3,8] 
  let array3 = [1,4,6,4] 

  // wanted
  let final = [
    [1,4,1],  <-- first array in the final
    [3,7,4],
    [3,3,6],
    [6,8,4]
  ]
```

First from each array (array1, array2, array3...) create first array in final one.
Second from each array create second one.. etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: The condition is not as special as you might think, it even has a well-known name :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const final = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
    final[i] = [array1[i], array2[i], array3[i]];
}
console.dir(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
let array1 = [1,3,3,6] 
  let array2 = [4,7,3,8] 
  let array3 = [1,4,6,4]
  finarray=[]
array1.forEach((x,i)=>{ finarray.push([x,array2[i],array3[i]])})
console.log(finarray)
```

Comment: You are welcome, can you accept my answer ?